# Convert apache2 htaccess to nginx htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

i have that code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In location: domain.com/systemy/sklep/
And I want to convert this htaccess to the nginx htaccess.
How to do this?